# fgetc read file line by line

Tags: c, file, fgetc

So I'm working on a function that will use `fgetc` to read a line into a buffer. so I can use that buffer as I please, and then refill the buffer with the next line. My function works however I have to repeat code outside of the for loop to process the last line as shown here:

```
for(i = 0, c = 1; ch != EOF; i++)
{
    ch = fgetc(grab);
    if(ch == 0x0A)
    {
        /*Process Line*/
        c = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        linetmp = realloc(line, (c + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if(!linetmp)
        {
            free(line);
            free(url);
            printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed!");
            return 1;
        }
        line = linetmp;
        line[c - 1] = ch;
        line[c] = 0x00;
        c++;
    }
}
/*repeat if(ch == 0x0A) statement*/
```

I would rather do this all in the same loop but am not sure on how I would go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you instead use `getline()` if you're on a POSIX system.

Also, your logic is strange since you check for `EOF` in the loop header only, but update `ch` inside the loop. That means it will run through with `ch == EOF`, before the loop condition is re-evaluated.

You should try putting the updating and the check together, making the loop header read like this:

```
for(i = 0, c = 1; (ch = fgetc()) != EOF; i++)
```

Also, you need to think about line separators, both `'\n'` (carriage return) and `'\n'` (line feed) can occur.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; for whatever reason I got into the habit of using `0x0D` and `0x0A` for my newline characters instead of `\r` `\n` respectively.

Comment: Alas this is not what I am looking for, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about getline! Used it once and then forgot about it when everyone was using fgets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should reallocate after each character. If you want to have the buffer at the smallest value needed, you could reallocate at the end with ( strlen() + 1); Also, there is a function fgets() which reads a line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int somefunc(FILE *grab)
{
   int current_size = 100;
   int data_size = current_size - 1;
   char *url = malloc(current_size);
   char *line = malloc(current_size);
   char *linetmp;
   int ch;
   ch = fgetc(grab);
   int i = 0;
   int c  = 0;
   while (ch  != EOF && ch != 0x0A )
   {
      i++;
      if ( i > data_size )
      {
         current_size = current_size * 2;
         data_size = current_size - 1;
         linetmp = realloc(line, current_size);
         if (!linetmp)
         {
            free(line);
            free(url);
            printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed!");
            return 1;
         }
         line = linetmp;
      }
      line[c] = ch;
      c++;
      ch = fgetc(grab);
   }
   line[c] = '\0';
   linetmp = realloc(line,strlen(line) + 1);
   line = linetmp;
   printf("we just read line->%s\n",line);
   free(line);
   free(url);
   return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
   char *cpFilename = "somefile.txt";
   FILE *fp = fopen(cpFilename,"r");
   if ( fp == NULL )
   {
      printf("ERROR: could not open %s\n",cpFilename);
      printf("Error code: %d\n",errno);
      perror("ERROR:");
      return 1;
   }
   int return_code = somefunc(fp);
   while (return_code != EOF && return_code != 1)
   {
      return_code = somefunc(fp);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```